# HP Load Runner is not invoking Browser for recording

Tags: performance-testing, load-testing, loadrunner, vugen

I am new to HP Load Runner. I was trying to record a script on my Virtual Machine. However while trying to record script in action, Vugen does not hit the HTTP based application. I am able to access the application using Internet Explorer.

Answer (score 0):

1. Has this combination ever worked or is this a new installation?
2. What recording options have you tried? (HTML, URL, Sockets, Proxy, ...)
3. What version of LoadRunner VUGEN?
4. What version of Internet Explorer
5. Have you tried a control site, such as the Flights Web application used as a part of the LoadRunner tutorial?
6. Have you tried a different browser?
7. Does this work on another machine? ( Look to differences to reconcile )
8. Have you satisfied all of the requirements for installation, including your credentials level on the host?
9. Do you have antivirus in the virtual machine which needs to be disabled?
10. Is VUGEN inside of the virtual machine instance with the browser or outside the virtual machine inside of the core operating system?

Comment: 1. This is new installation and it was working fine on my XP Virtual Machine
  2. trying to hit a URL and do login to application
  3. version 12.01
  4. IE 11 - edge
  5. I have not tried
  6. The URL does not work with other browsers as it requires java to run. JAVA is not supported in google chrome or mozilla by default
  7. Yes, it works in other Windows 7 Virtual machines
  8. Yes, all the pre requisites have been completed 
  9. I do have antivirus on my Virtual Machine. It is not disabled
  10.  VuGen is inside Virtual Machine Instance with the browser

Comment: The answer to 2 suggests you need training as your answer is out of context with the question.   Research the proxy recorder and setup your recording environment for that path

Comment: I agree with you James, however to attend a training and try out the things, I guess I would need load runner installed on my machine. I was trying on what they covered for the session and it does not work for me so posted this question. Thanks for your advice... I will definitely checkout for proper training..

Comment: When you attend training with an HP authorized training center and a certified HP instructor, machines full configured for the training class software are provided for the controlled setting of the class.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the default path for Internet Explorer(C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe) was incorrect in HP load Runner. After manually selecting the web browser at correct path(C:\Program Files (x86)\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe), Load runner started to record the scripts.

Thanks all.